# Can someone suggest a way to compress my page source to the absolute minimum file size?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I'm developing a modern site that needs to be accessed out in the boonies, mostly over cellphone networks that may not even be 3G.

I need my uncacheable page source to be the smallest possible size. Suggestions?

That is to say, when you go to 'view page source' and see the text file containing the source, how can I transfer that source (excluding cached resources) in the smallest possible file size? Saving kilobytes matters in this case.

Could you say, rename html attributes to 'A1', 'A2' from their longform names, get rid of all comments and whitespace, then compress the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I need my uncacheable page source to be the smallest possible size. Suggestions?

I normally see this handled by the web server (or sometimes, what ever is in front of the server).

What does the architecture look like? If you are using `nginx` as a front end/load balancer, see the [PageSpeed](http://ngxpagespeed.com/ngx_pagespeed_example/) from [3rd Party Modules](http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules).

> ... then compress the file

You have to be careful with this. Its often recommended to turn off compression. [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME_%28security_exploit%29) and [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME_%28security_exploit%29) use compression to leak sensitive material like access tokens. (Or, leave compression enabled and accept the risk).

Comment: Haven't got that far. I don't forsee this requiring a load balancer because my customers would be local and there are very few of them. I think Id just have one server hosting IIS, at least to start with.

Comment: I think there's a PageSpeed port for IIS at http://www.iispeed.com/. I've never used it though. Sorry.

Comment: Wow, that's quite surprising to me that compressing the site opens up a security hole. Thanks for this, I'll take a look at it later when I have something meaningful to test.

Comment: Could you turn on compression only on download, but not upload?